# Problems with cross-validation in R

Tags: r, analytics

I run the following model in R:

```
 g<-lm(NA.~ PC + I(1/(I(DSET$SPCI) * I(DSET$PC + DSET$PI))),data=DSET)
```

It runs OK. But when I want to cross-validated the same model:

```
a<-CVlm(df=DSET,form.lm = g ,m=5)
```

The result is the following message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = form, data = df[rows.in, ], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'I(1/(I(DSET$SPCI) * I(DSET$PC + DSET$PI)))')
```

EDIT:

I run the model g again in the following way:

```
g<-lm(NA.~ PC + I(1/(SPCI * (PC + PI))),data=DSET)
```

The output was the same as the first way. Then, I cross-validate with the same code and it run.

So my question is: Why `I(1/(I(DSET$SPCI) * I(DSET$PC + DSET$PI))` is not accepted by the code of cross-validation and gives that message?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's your _only_ problem, but your formula is all messed up. You should never, ever use `$` inside a formula specification. That's the whole point of having a separate `data` argument. I'm also suspicious of the `NA.`. That seems like a weird variable name.

Comment: The name of the atribute was NA, so R changed the name to NA. to not confuse with NA. There isn`t missing values in my data frame.

Comment: That seems fine. The only reason I asked about that piece is because `.` has a special meaning in formulas and it wasn't entirely clear, based on the other stuff that's wrong in the formula, whether you meant to be using it in that sense or not.

Comment: Your formula needs to be implicitly written (hence the `data` argument), not explicitly by calling "outside" variables through `$`.

Comment: Which package contains the function `CVlm`? Also, have you considered making new variables instead of applying arithmetic operations in the formula itself?

Comment: The DAAG package contains CVlm.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably fifth time I am here and always wondering why the answer given by @jlhoward does not work. So for future readers (including me), to make this code work, replace `df` by `data` as follows:

```
CVlm(data=DSET,form.lm = form ,m=5)
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DAAG/DAAG.pdf), page 47.

Answer (score 0):

In `CVlm(...)` the `form.lm` parameter neds to be a *formula*, you are passing *model* (the result of a fit).

Try something like this:

```
form <- NA.~ PC + I(1/(SPCI * (PC + PI)))
g    <- lm(form, data=DSET)
a    <- CVlm(df=DSET,form.lm = form ,m=5)
```